# Не удается выполнить json запрос python

Tags: python, json

Столкнулся вот с таким кодом ошибки
Код ошибки: `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response`
Я банально не понимаю в чем проблема,если синтаксис программы правильный

```
import json
import urllib.request 
import requests



headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}

URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/zuck/?__a=1'

r = requests.get(URL,headers=headers)
data = json.loads(r)
print("id",data['graphql']['user']['id'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
>>> get_user_id('dwalinforkbeard')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 75, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 592, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(conn, method, url,
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 352, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 831, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 254, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020CD774F160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 413, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 287, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.instagram.comdwalinforkbeard', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?__a=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020CD774F160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    get_user_id('dwalinforkbeard')
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\main.py.py", line 8, in get_user_id
    r = requests.get(f'{URL}{username}/?__a=1', headers=HEADERS)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 487, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.instagram.comdwalinforkbeard', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?__a=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020CD774F160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Comment: Ты пытаешься парсить объект Response. Он у тебя присваивается переменной r. А тебе надо парсить его содержимое. Посмотри его атрибуты и методы.

Comment: data = json.loads(r.content)

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что вам возвращается `json`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка `JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response` сообщает о том, что вы не там ищете данные. Они не в `Response`, а в его содержимом:

```
import json
import requests

URL = 'https://www.instagram.com'
HEADERS={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}

def get_user_id(username):
    r = requests.get(f'{URL}/{username}/?__a=1', headers=HEADERS)
    data = json.loads(r.content)

    if data:
        return int(data['graphql']['user']['id'])

    return -1
```

При использовании возвращает id или -1, если пользователь не найден:

```
>>> get_user_id('dwalinforkbeard')
6426589779
>>> get_user_id('zuck')
314216
>>> get_user_id('kherg87')
-1
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ!Но почему-то у меня выбивает следующее                                                
```object at 0x000001C3840EF160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))```

Comment: @justdeveloper1 как запускаете?

Comment: @Jask_oS Через консоль IDLE Python.Пример привел выше

Comment: @justdeveloper1 если этот ответ просто скопировать, не внося изменений, и запустить - появляется ошибка?

Comment: В данном случае - да

Comment: @justdeveloper1 добавьте текстом полный трейс ошибки?

Comment: Трейс с ошибкой добавил выше

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119099/discussion-between-jack-os-and-justdeveloper1).

Comment: @Jask_oS Каким образом можно взять значения cookie для корректной работы?

Answer (score 2):

Response это не JSON. В ответ приходит ответ с JSON, заголовками и прочими данными, надо найти свойство, в котором находится JSON, обычно это `data`